# How can I send an .so file to a MySQL instance on Google Cloud?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, user-defined-functions, google-cloud-sql

I am actually using an aggregate User Defined Function (UDF) and I have compiled a shared object file (.so).

In my local instance it is all right. I just pushed the file to my `/usr/local/mysql/plugins` folder.

The problem is: Now I have to push the UDF file to my remote instance running in google cloud and I have no idea how can I do that. I have searched a lot and didn't find any answer.

Does anyone have a clue about how it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud SQL [does not support UDFs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/features#unsupported_statements).

Comment: This is really frustrating. MySQL does not have support to median calculations and Google Cloud SQL does not have support to UDFs.
Thank you for the answer, I really didn't find this part of documentation.